# ¿Cómo reducir tamaño de imagen en C#?

Tags: c#, imagen

Buenas tengo una consulta en C# existe alguna manera de reducir el tamaño de una imagen para subirla a otra ruta, me refiero al tamaño en **megabyte** no al tamaño de alto y ancho de la imagen, muchas gracias de antemano!

```
String ruta = rutaarchivo + fucodigo.FileName.ToString();
fucodigo.PostedFile.SaveAs(ruta);
```

Por ejemplo antes del SaveAs(ruta) reducirle el tamaño en megabyte a una calidad mas baja

Comment: Sí, existen varias formas. De las que conozco, te sugiero usar la API de TinyPNG, te ahorras tiempo. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas ya encontré la solución utilice esto:

```
System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(ruta); 
var newImage = ScaleImage(image, 300, 400);
```

y me funciono luego elimine la imagen anterior y listo, muchas gracias!